# Nodejs os.networkInterfaces returning empty object

Tags: node.js, operating-system, mac-address

I am trying to get the mac address from the client's machine. I did some seaching and found some npm packages. But many seem to use the included `os` module to do a `os.networkInterfaces()` and go further from there.

But when I try to get all the interfaces using the `os` module it returns an empty object. I read in the documentation that it returns interfaces that have been assigned a network address.

So I am a little confused as to what I am doing wrong, since in my opinion there is no reason not to work.

Could anyone help me get to the sollution of finding the client's mac address please?

All help would be appreciated

Comment: How did you solve this eventually? I'm experiencing the same thing on Windows

Comment: Same thing here. It returned an empty Object for me both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04